# Why is Firefox 3.5.7 constantly crashing?

Tags: firefox

This has been happening for the last week or so.

It happens if I don't access it for a while. As long as I keep using it, it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this didn't happen with version 3.5.6?

- check your extensions and make sure they're all up-to-date.
- if this doesn't help, start disabling the extensions one by one to eliminate the culprit.
- if that fails: backup Firefox with [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109) (Firefox Environment Backup) or [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/) (a backup is always handy to have anyway :), uninstall Firefox **completely** and reinstall it, then restore your profile, bookmarks and addons from the backup.
- as a last resort, you can revert back to version 3.5.6 which you can download [here](http://www.filehippo.com/download_firefox/6732/).

Comment: Who knows from 3.5.6? Whatever it was, it worked.

With my expertise, I think I'll just tolerate it until 3.5.7?? .8??.
Thanks and regards.

Comment: well, 3.5.7 was released only 6 days ago.

Comment: I'm not clear. I'm not knowledgable. Thanks for your information.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this problem, I suggest to just upgrade it to 3.6 version. It will become stable. I was also not able to further from my home page Google. Then, I just click help, Check for updates and Upgraded it to latest version 3.6. I don't know this is right solution or not, but it works for me.

Comment: Thanks. I did this, but it still occasionally.